# Tomcat 6 ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH / ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap

Tags: tomcat6, encryption, mismatch

I’ve trouble to use a browser for accessing my SSL/TLS enabled tomcat-6.0.36-windows-x64 server. It works fine with openssl but not with any browser.

Initializing looks fine:

`16.01.2013 16:45:09 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init`

`INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443`

Also openSSL:
`openssl s_client -tls1 -connect localhost:8443:`
Result:

`New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA`

`Server public key is 256 bit`

`Secure Renegotiation IS supported`

`Compression: NONE`

`Expansion: NONE`

`SSL-Session:`

```
Protocol  : TLSv1
```

`Cipher    : ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA`

Only web-browsers don’t work:

**Firefox 15.0.1 says: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap**

**Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**

That’s the tomcat configuration:

`Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"

    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150"
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true"

           SSLProtocol="all"

           enableLookups="false" 
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" 
           SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="../ecc_servercert.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="../ec_serverkey.pem"`

The certificate is based on a ecliptic curves algorithm:

`openssl ecparam -out c:\ecc\ec_serverkey.pem -name secp256k1 -genkey`

`openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365 -key c:\ecc\ec_serverkey.pem -out  c:\ecc\ecc_servercert.crt`

Hope someone has an idea? Accourding to hours of searching, the browers should support this configuariton ...

Ragards, Tobi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that there are two possibilities:

1. Either you use the APR connector and Tomcat native libraries as well, so it will throw the error.(more info:http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File)
2. Or you use the same port for both http & https: in your connector you use 8443 which is usually used for http.(have you tried o use port="443" not "8443"?)

Comment: It was actually a lag in browsers ecc support and tomcats dcc configuration. openssl is much more failure tolerant. but you gave to only answer, so you get the green Ok :-)

Answer (score 0):

ashiii is incorrect, it's because the ecc curve `secp256k1` is not supported in chrome or firefox.

`prime256v1` and `secp384r1` are good alternatives. see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/78621/which-elliptic-curve-should-i-use